# GRASS r.viewshed Command Line Error: Raster map <rasterfile> not found

Tags: grass-gis, r.watershed, cmd

I'm struggling to make sense of the grass command line syntax for specifying a raster geotif as an input parameter for a watershed analysis using a DEM tif.  I may also have the user folder setup, database, mapsets completely wrong too.
The commands are to be run from the CMD in windows 10 using GRASS 7.6.

My command:

```
grass76 --text C:\Temp\grass\newLocation\PERMANENT --exec r.watershed -s elevation="C:\Temp\grass\database\dem.tif" threshold=10000
```

Message:

```
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Executing <r.watershed -s elevation=C:\Temp\grass\database\dem.tif threshold=10000> ...
SECTION 1a (of 5): Initiating Memory.
ERROR: Raster map <C:\Temp\grass\database\dem.tif> not found
WARNING: Subprocess failed with exit code 1
Execution of <r.watershed -s elevation=C:\Temp\grass\database\dem.tif threshold=10000> finished.
Cleaning up temporary files...
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've tried without " around the filepath, with forward slashes, within <>.
I've copied the dem.tif to all the folders: 'C:\Temp\grass\newLocation', 'C:\Temp\grass\newLocation\command', 'C:\Temp\grass\newLocation\PERMANENT', 'C:\Temp\grass\database'

Any obvious syntax problems?

It seems like the --exec is successfully recognising I want to run a command put claims there is a raster file path or file access issue...

I want to avoid any setting up of a GRASS GIS Database directory, GRASS Location or a Mapset...whatever that is.

I just want to be able to run GRASS commands from the command prompt - in reality probably automated via python and subprocess and to change to input parameters such as the data source and output files.  So I would prefer to do that via within the command itself.  I want to avoid user input of setting up an environment.

Is that possible?

Have I mucked up the setup which is causing issues? (I set EPSG of 27700 when creating the user folder).

[image: Current GRASS setup]

Comment: If you don't want to import the taster file in a Grass location/mapset Use  [r.external](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.external.html) ( [Working with external data in GRASS 7](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_external_data_in_GRASS_7))

Comment: I had a go with that: grass76 r.external input=c:\grassdata\dem.tif output=dem.  The result always tries to put my user folder in front of it and removes the filename.  Result: ERROR: Location <C:\Users\aallan.BUROHAPPOLD\input=c:\grassdata> doesn't exist.  The examples don't seem to mention filepaths or anything that looks like a windows filepath anyway.

Comment: BTW: please consider to upgrade to GRASS GIS 7.8: https://grass.osgeo.org/news/2020_10_05_grass_gis_7_8_4_released/ It comes with many (!) improvements.

Comment: I have grass 7.8 as well, and that doesn't help with the raster file paths issue.  Does anyone have a working example with Windows file paths (and not in a user folder)?  Preferably with spaces in the path, as this is a far more realistic- real world example when dealing with data from different sources...